# Codeigniter Active Records LIKE Query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am making a news website with Codeigniter, and I have an Articles **MySQL** table like
ID,Title,Body,Categories,Created etc...

In Categories field I have category separated with comma(,) like...

- Article 1 Categories : National,Crime,Cinema
- Article 2 Categories : National,City,Drama
- Article 3 Categories : Funny,International,Cinema
- Article 4 Categories : National,Crime,Cinema

I want to fetch article with Specific Category.. like National **(1,2,4)**.
I tried many methods but nothing seems to work.

Please Help Thanks.

Comment: Since it is not finished, i would really consider changing of db structure... you should have separate category table, and one additional table for article-category connection (id,cat_id, article_id). Then you can get what you want relatively easy. If you want to keep this scheme: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302967/running-a-select-on-a-list-of-comma-separated-values-in-php maybe this could help.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `FIND_IN_SET` method to query your `Categories` field

`FIND_IN_SET('Crime', your_table.Categories)`

Your approach has a number of shortcomings,  It would def be more scalable in the long run to change your tables relationship to `Categories`.  You can use a manytomany relationship and a join table to more easily query your categories.

FIND_IN_SET will do a full table scan,  and using this comma seperated way will be very difficult to aggregate, and get article/category counts.

---

[Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

Bill Karwin has included this anti pattern as the first chapter in his excellent book.

Comment: Thanks for reply... i will surely try your approach and let you know if its worked. thanks a lot.